# Checking if a user disconnects using Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to check if a user disconnects from my site, how would I go about doing this?

I am doing this in order to check if a user is "online" or not.

Comment: ...What? I suppose you could use JS to detect when they close the window and then send a message with AJAX to the server to say they did, or you could use inactivity (they haven't loaded a page in X minutes). What have you tried?

Comment: I could try AJAX I suppose. I haven't tried anything, I have googled a lot but I have not really found a straight forward solution.

Comment: That's kind of because there isn't one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you can't tell that the user has left your site on the server-side. The common way to do what you want to achieve is to use a time limit after the last known request as a cutoff between the online/offline states.

To make this more accurate you can have a script on the client-side that does regular AJAX polling, if you must consider that a user is online long after their last request while your site is still open in a tab. If you must check that the user has the tab active, make that request conditional on recent mouse or keyboard events.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it more.